# How can I handle errors in a robot code

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have built a robot which basicaly crawls websites starting at the root, parses the page, saves all the internal links, and then moves to the first page in the link list, parses it and so on.

I know its not really optimized to run this sort of bot in PHP but as it's the only language I happen to know well enough, thats the one I chose.

I came accross all sort of issues : pages returning 404, then pages being redirected then pages which are not parsable (werid case of few pages that return a few words when being parsed but return the entire expected body when you send a GET http request), etc...

Anyway I reckon I have made the robot so it can go through 99.5% of the pages it parses, but yet there are some pages that are not parsable and at that point my bot crashes (about 1 page out of 400 make the bot crash, and as crashing I mean, I just get a fatal error, the code just stops then).

Now my question is : how can I prevent this from happening ? I am not asking how to fix a bug I cant even debug (they re most of the time times out, so not very easy to debug), I'd liek to know how to handle those errors. Is there a way to refresh the page in case a certain type of error occurs ? Is there a way to go around those time out fatal errors ?

I cannot see the point of showing you any sort of code, although i will if you feel the need of checking a certain part of it.

Thank you

Comment: I think a better question is [`How can I detect a 400 error with PHP?`](http://bit.ly/1bx7bmZ).

Comment: This is not a better question to ask, those poages which make the bot crash return 200 (pretty much 95% of the time). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try detecting redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to use a try{} catch(){} block.

[http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php][1]

You put the part of the parser into the try block, and if an error is thrown, feed some default values and go to the next link.

If you are getting fatal errors (which I think you can't catch with try), then you could also try to break each step download/parsing into a separate php file that is called with the url it needs to lookup via curl. This kind of poor man's parallelization will cause you to incurr a lot of overhead though and is probably not necessarily how php "should" be used, but should work. You'll also need to store the results in a database / text file.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Results are so far stored in session variables (i was surprise to see sessions could handle over 1MB of informations). I will try the try{} and catch{} method and see where this leads me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Alright this makes my life a bit easier since it avoids a few errors (the time out remains), those few are good enough for the time being.